# How to order child records when referenced from a parent object in PeeWee ORM

Tags: python, peewee

How do I specify an order for the records returned via a foreign key in Peewee?

I have the following (simplified) model;

```
class Order(peewee.Model):
    order_no = peewee.CharField()

class OrderLine(peewee.Model):
    order_item = peewee.CharField()
    quantity = peewee.IntegerField()
    price = peewee.DecimalField()

    order = peewee.ForeignKeyField(Order)
```

When I fetch an order using `my_order = Order.get(1234)` I would like to then iterate through the order lines in a specific order, sometimes in `order_item` order, sometimes in `quantity` order. Is there a way to do this? At the moment they seem to come back in `order_item.id` order from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The back-ref of the foreign-key (`Order.orderline_set`) is just a wrapper around a select query, so you can order it how you wish:

```
for item in order.orderline_set.order_by(OrderLine.quantity):
    ...
```